# How to send extra data with AJAX form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a HTML form. It contains a file input.

After browsing a file, I want to send that file to server.

I have written code to submit the form. & I am getting file & its data on server.

I want to send some data while submitting form, which will be used on server. How this can be done? How to send data form client side & how to read it on server?

```
$("#myForm").ajaxForm({ 
    success : function(data) { 
        var localdata = JSON.parse(data); 
    }, 
    dataType : "text" 
}).submit(); 


<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/myformSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div class="custom-upload fl"> 
        <input type="file" id="selectFile" name="selectFile">                 
        <div class="fileupload"></div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="fl" style="padding: 1px 0 0 5px;"> 
        <input name="input4" type="button" class="button submit upload" value="Upload" tabindex="100" /> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: javascript code - $("#myForm").ajaxForm({
    success : function(data) {
     var localdata = JSON.parse(data);
    },
    dataType : "text"
   }).submit();

Comment: html code - 
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/myformSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="custom-upload fl">
  <input type="file" id="selectFile" name="selectFile">
  <div class="fileupload"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="fl" style="padding: 1px 0 0 5px;">
  <input name="input4" type="button" class="button submit upload" value="Upload" tabindex="100" />
 </div>
</form>

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), so you should add `data` property to the options of your `ajaxForm()` call. (`data` property is, according to plugin's documentation, *an object containing extra data that should be submitted along with the form*).

```
$("#myForm").ajaxForm({ 
    success : function(data) { 
        var localdata = JSON.parse(data); 
    }, 
    dataType : "text",
    data: { 
        yourParam1: "yourValue1", 
        yourParam2: ...
    }
}).submit();
```

As for processing the data on the server, it would be probably good, if you started with reading the tutorial, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html (or watch [a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOljldJHtgz6BiP-tR8mAndbBYX0d0j6v)). Hint: the data (form values + the additional data) are request parameters.

Comment: Hi, it is working with data as key. Thank you very much for the solution.